# Unable to prove -100000000000000 eligible as an long input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, long-integer

I have written a program to determine whether any input fits the range of various data-types in java, and if it does the print the eligible data-types.

The program first takes an integer input to determine the total constants for which
I want to test the eligibility. It then runs a loop the required number of times determined by the query, to check eligibility for each constant entered.

The problem which I am facing is that-- I am checking the eligibility for a single input, but when I enter "-100000000000000"(-1 followed by 14 zeroes), no output comes and the cursor takes the input and then just blinks indefinitely.

Any other constant input gives desired output, but the problem with the program happens only after I enter "-100000000000000". I have been trying to solve the problem myself for a long time now, and hence any lead would help me.

Here is my code -->

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
class Solution{
public static void main(String []argh)
{



    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {

        try
        {
            long x=sc.nextLong();
            System.out.println(x+" can be fitted in:");
            if(x>=-128 && x<=127){
                System.out.println("* byte");
            }
            if(x>=(int)(pow(-2.00,15.00)) && x<=(int)(pow(2.00,15.00)-1)){
                System.out.println("* short");
            }
            if(x>=(int)(pow(-2.00,31.00)) && x<=(int)(pow(2.00,31.00)-1)){
                System.out.println("* int");
            }
            if(x>=(int)(pow(-2.00,63.00)) && x<=(int)(pow(2.00,63.00)-1)){
                System.out.println("* long");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(sc.next()+" can't be fitted anywhere.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in your code that you're trying to parse `pow(-2.00,63.00)` to an Integer, which will not return the value you're expecting.

You can just replace your casting in the Long data-type check like this:

```
if(x>=(long)(pow(-2.00,63.00)) && x<=(long)(pow(2.00,63.00)-1)){
    System.out.println("* long");
}
```

Also, just in case you didn't knew, you could simply use "Long.MIN_VALUE | Long.MAX_VALUE" instead of "pow(-2.00,63.00) and pow(2.00,63.00)-1" respectively. Same goes for the others data-types (Byte, Short, Integer).

Comment: Links: [`Long.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#MIN_VALUE) and [`Long.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: And even if these constants would not exist, `1L<<63` is a faster way to calculate 2^63.